# How to query the three best players in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table:

```
NAME   | SCORE
ALICE  | 100
BOB    | 90
CHARLES| 90
DUKE   | 80
EVE    | 70
...
```

My question is the following:

How can I extract with one query the name of the three best players? In my example the query should return **four** rows (ALICE, BOB, CHARLES and DUKE) because there are two silver medalists (they both have 90 points).

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Unless this is homework, in the real world I would handle the extra row(s) in code and move on.

Comment: @tgkprog Why querying and processing 10000 rows if you need only 3 ?

Comment: I thought the issue was that you wanted only 3 rows but getting 4. So I meant get one extra and discard it in code. But I see what you mean now. Its easier in my sql :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oracle has the [`DENSE_RANK`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions043.htm) analytical function for that exact purpose:

```
select name, score from (
  select name, score, dense_rank() over(order by score desc nulls last) rank
  --                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^
  --                                                 reject NULL score at the end
  from t
) V
where rank < 4
order by rank, name
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/88445/5

Comment: Nice solution. I like it. It is more readable than the solution of beny23 (which also works). On the other hand if there is a record with null score than that row will be the first. Of course it can be handled with an nvl function or an order by nulls last modifier.

Comment: @László I've edited my answer to use the `NULLS LAST` specifier in the `ORDER BY` clause. This should deal elegantly with the NULL score issue.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following

```
select * 
  from table1
 where score >=
   (select score from (
     select score, rownum r from (
      select distinct score from table1 order by score desc
     ) where rownum <= 3
   ) where r = 3)
order by score desc
```

See also this SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/23e68/1

Comment: Thank you. It seems ok. It would be nice to find a solution with less subqueries.

Comment: Note, the nested subqueries with rownum are an Oracle pattern and it is quite efficient at it (depending on the indeces you've defined), so while it looks complex, it's fairly efficient.

Comment: You might find me stupid to mention this, but i found the need for the same. When Score is VARCHAR2, then ORDER BY DESC fails as then 100 comes at the last.
But in some real applications(getting value from some business logic after taking it from frontend) the data might be in VARCHAR2 too which needed the parsing.
So just wanted you to give it a sight.
Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2a4b0/1